# ItemFactory Class - Creates copies of predefined items by name and returns by pointer

Tags: c++, json, factory-method

I'm working on writing a text based RPG game, and I've decided to define each possible item as a JSON file in a specific directory. The item factory is meant to act as a singleton, and uses static members to store all possible items. I feel like the whole structure might need a redesign, because I am told that singletons are evil. Also feel free to point anything out that I might be doing that will come back to bite me.

## ItemFactory.hpp

```
#ifndef ITEMFACTORY__HPP
#define ITEMFACTORY__HPP

#include "Item.hpp"

/**
 * \brief Generates new item objects from the defaults that are available.
 *        
 *        Allows for the location files to define items by a code or string
 *        rather than listing all of their attributes. Also better validation
 *        is added by restricting the items to being defined in a directory.
 */
class ItemFactory {
    // Attributes
    private :
        static std::vector<Item> m_validItems;
        static std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>> m_validTypes;

        void loadItem(std::string file);

        void loadValidItemTypes(std::string itemTypesFile);
    // Operations
    public :
        ItemFactory (std::string itemDir);
        ItemFactory ();

        /**
         * \brief decides whether the type listed is valid.
         * \param name (???)
         * \return bool
         */
        bool validateType (std::string type);

        /**\return copy of item requested, null if not found.
         */
        Item* getByName (std::string name);

        void listItems (std::ostream& out);
};

#endif
```

## ItemFactory.cpp

```
#include "../include/ItemFactory.hpp"
#include "../lib/tinydir.h"
#include "../include/Misc.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>> ItemFactory::m_validTypes = {};
std::vector<Item> ItemFactory::m_validItems = {};


ItemFactory::ItemFactory (std::string itemDir) {
    this->loadValidItemTypes("config/itemtypes.json");

    // load valid items
    tinydir_dir dir;
    tinydir_open(&dir, itemDir.c_str());
    while(dir.has_next) {
        tinydir_file file;
        tinydir_readfile(&dir, &file);
        if(file.is_reg) {
            this->loadItem(file.path);
        }
        tinydir_next(&dir);
    }
    tinydir_close(&dir);
}

ItemFactory::ItemFactory() { }

void ItemFactory::loadItem(std::string file) {
    json j;
    JSON_FROM_FILE(j, file);

    Item itm(j, this);
    m_validItems.push_back(itm);
}

bool ItemFactory::validateType(std::string type) {
    return m_validTypes.count(type);
}

void ItemFactory::listItems(std::ostream& out) {
    for(auto& itm : m_validItems)
        out << itm.getName() << " - " << itm.getType() << std::endl;
}

void ItemFactory::loadValidItemTypes(std::string itemTypesFile) {
    json j;
    JSON_FROM_FILE(j, itemTypesFile);
    if(!j.is_object())
        throw "ItemTypesFile must contain a json object";
    for(json::iterator it = j.begin(); it != j.end(); ++it) {
        std::vector<std::string> v;
        //TODO: add loading of valid attributes for each type
        m_validTypes.insert(std::make_pair((std::string)it.key(), v));
    }
}

Item* ItemFactory::getByName(std::string name) {
    auto it = std::find_if(m_validItems.begin(), m_validItems.end(),
        [&name](Item const& item) {
            return item.getName() == name;
        });
    if(it == m_validItems.end())
        throw "Can't find requested item";
    return new Item(*it);
}
```

## Item.hpp

```
#ifndef ITEM__HPP
#define ITEM__HPP

#include "EntityBase.hpp"
#include <map>

class ItemFactory;

class Item : public EntityBase {
    // Attributes
    private :
        std::string m_type;
        std::map<std::string,int> m_attributes;
        /// Price to buy from a store
        int m_buyPrice;
        /// Money returned for selling to store.
        int m_sellPrice;

        ItemFactory* m_factory;
    public:
        Item(json j, ItemFactory* factory);
        Item(const Item& itm);

        std::string getType();
};

#include "ItemFactory.hpp"

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

### General:

- Pass `std::string` by `const&`, so `void loadItem(std::string const& file);` etc.
- I don't know what the `json` type looks like, but it should probably be passed by const& into the `Item` constructor too.
- The `// Attributes` and `// Operations` comments aren't really true (and they're rather unnecessary).
- There's no reason to `#include "ItemFactory.hpp"` at the end of `Item.hpp`. This should be done at the top of the cpp file instead.

### Const Correctness:

- Any function that doesn't modify the state of the class instance (i.e. member variables) should be declared `const` (e.g. `bool validateType(std::string const& type) const;`).
- Any function that doesn't need access to members of a class instance should be static. (In this case, that could actually be all of the functions!)
- It looks like all the public `ItemFactory` member functions should be `const` or `static`, so `Item` should probably store a `const*` to the `ItemFactory`.
- In `listItems()`, the for loop should use `auto const&`, as the items aren't being altered.

### Design:

It's true that singletons have downsides, and should generally be avoided. But this class has problems with consistency, and isn't a true singleton either.

The class should either be completely static (so that there's no reason to create an instance of it):

```
class ItemFactory {
    private :
        static std::vector<Item> m_validItems;
        static std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>> m_validTypes;

        static void loadItem(std::string const& file);
        static void loadValidItemTypes(std::string const& itemTypesFile);

    public :

        static void loadItems(std::string const& itemDir); // constructor replaced with this function!

        static bool validateType(std::string const& type);
        static Item* getByName (std::string name);
        static void listItems (std::ostream& out);
};

...

void doSomething() {
    ItemFactory::validateType("foo"); // don't need an instance to use the factory
}
```

Or (better) the class should have no static members (and no default constructor) and be passed by `const&` to where it's needed:

```
ItemFactory factory("itemDir");

doSomethingWithItemFactory(factory);

...

void doSomethingWithItemFactory(ItemFactory const& factory) {
    factory.validateType("foo"); // use the factory
}
```

This ensures that the factory is only used after loading the items.